# Evaluating limit with $\frac{1}{x}$ exponent

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you evaluate this limit without L'hopital rule?

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}\log((e^{\pi x} -1)$$

From that: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \log((e^{\pi x} -1)^{\frac{1}{x}})$ but now I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\log(e^{\pi x}-1)=\log\left(e^{\pi x}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}}\right)\right)=\log(e^{\pi x})+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}}\right)=\pi x+\log\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{\pi x}}\right)$$